# MVC ViewModel collections are null on postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a view model which contains a class reference and 2 IEnumerable collections.

```
public class BuildingTypeViewModel
{
    public Static_Item BuildingType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Reading_Type> ReadingTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Building_Type_Reading> BuildingReadings { get; set; }
}
```

I populate this ViewModel in the Edit action on the controller

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {            
        Static_Item staticItem = db.Static_Item.Find(id);

        BuildingTypeViewModel model = new BuildingTypeViewModel
        {
            BuildingType = staticItem,
            ReadingTypes=db.Reading_Type.ToList(),
            BuildingReadings = db.Building_Type_Reading.Where(bt => bt.UN_Building_Type == staticItem.UN_Building_Type).ToList()
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

Building type on the view model is a class with an ID and Description and the data would be something like this:

```
UN_Building_Type=1, Description = "Hospital"
```

The IEnumerable of Reading_Type's would be like this:

```
UN_Reading_Type = 1, Description = "Electric"    
UN_Reading_Type = 2, Description = "Gas"
```

The IEnumerable of Building_Type_Readings would be like this:

```
UN_Building_Type_Readings=1, UN_Building_Type=1, UN_Reading_Type = 1, Typical=300, Good=150
UN_Building_Type_Readings=2, UN_Building_Type=1, UN_Reading_Type = 2, Typical=800, Good=400
```

I load this data into my view:

```
@model SSE.Enterprise.EE_Web_Portal.Models.BuildingTypeViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Static_Item</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BuildingType.UN_Building_Type)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BuildingType.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BuildingType.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BuildingType.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Building Readings</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th/>
                        <th>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.BuildingReadings.FirstOrDefault().Typical)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BuildingReadings.FirstOrDefault().Good)
                        </th>
                    </tr>

                    @foreach (var item in Model.ReadingTypes)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.Label(item.Description)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BuildingReadings.FirstOrDefault(b => b.UN_Reading_Type == item.UN_Reading_Type).Typical, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BuildingReadings.FirstOrDefault(b => b.UN_Reading_Type == item.UN_Reading_Type).Good, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Here is my edit postback method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "BuildingType")] BuildingTypeViewModel model)
    {   
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

When the page is posted back the 2 IEnumerable collections are null so I'm not able to save the data that has been entered.

Any idea?

Ta

Comment: shouldn't your beginform have more details? like:  using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post,...

Comment: @MarkHomer: Nope. All that is optional. If you don't pass an action and controller, the current action and controller are used. The default is POST, so no need to set that either.

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls - inspect the html your generating. The `name` attributes have no relationship at all to your mdoel. You need to use a `for` loop (and your collection properties need to be `IList<T>` not `IEnumerable<T>`. Or alternatively you need to use custom `EditorTemplates` for typeof `Reading_Type` and `Building_Type_Reading`

Comment: @StephenMuecke looking at the View I would agree with that, although not looked too closely all looks a bit of a mess lol looks like a nightmare to debug, I would review the design

Comment: @MarkHomer, whenever you see something in a view as horrible as `m=> m.BuildingReadings.FirstOrDefault(b => b.UN_Reading_Type == item.UN_Reading_Type).Typical` you can be sure it needs to be redesigned :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, by specifying the attribute `Bind(Include = "BuildingType")` you're telling MVC to only bind this single property. Remove the attribute, and MVC will try to bind your 2 `IEnumerable` collections.

Next, check your `@Html.EditorFor` calls. I'm not sure MVC can understand `FirstOrDefault` inside. Try avoiding LINQ selectors inside your view.

And after that, as @will mentioned, try changing `IEnumerable` to `List`.

Comment: You are correct. To properly bind, you'll need to index the items in the collection, i.e. `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BuildingReadings[0].Typical)`

Comment: I've removed the Bind attribute and the LINQ and it's still the same

Comment: Try and look at the HTML source of the page you're getting. Your inputs should look like this: `<input name="BuildingReadings[0].Typical" ... >`, `<input name="BuildingReadings[0].Good" ... >`, etc. If all else fails, you can always follow any tutorial on binding to collections in MVC (like [this one](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)), then gradually modify it to match your view model and see at which step the binding fails.